# Bounce animation won't work

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to bounce an a `<div>` containing an image, but it won't work and I'm not sure why.

This is my code:

```
@keyframes bounce
{
    from {
        left: 0px;
    }
    to {
        right: 30px;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes bounce /* Firefox */
{
    from {
        left: 0px;
    }
    to {
        right: 30px;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce /* Safari and Chrome */
{
    from {
        left: 0px;
    }
    to {
        right: 30px;
    }
} 

#DanielFace
{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 145px;
    height: 165px;
    background-image: url(../images/daniel/fun.png);
    animation: bounce 1s;
    -moz-animation: bounce 1s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: bounce 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

Comment: In what way does it "not work"? Personally I'd use some very simple JS to do this - CSS is for styling, not animating.

Comment: @Kolink: CSS is *way* better for animating. Some things. Maybe not this.

Comment: it present the image, but the image wont bounce.

Comment: @minitech: Not if you know how to use JS properly ;)

Comment: @Kolink: Beg differ: http://jsfiddle.net/s3Fm9/ Now you go fill in the JS part ;) Go ahead, use jQuery.

Comment: @minitech: http://jsfiddle.net/s3Fm9/1/ There you go. Of course, my method is more efficient with more complex animations.

Comment: @Kolink: Nice one. I'm not going to ask for easing this time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of two things.

First `left` and `right` won't do anything with the object given that CSS. Those values will only apply if the `position` of the element is something other than `static` (the default).

Secondly, they are conflicting values, so you will not get the animated effect you are looking for. What you are saying now is basically stretch this element, except you've given it a static width so it won't. What do you want the image to do on your page exactly?

Comment: You'll want to set _either_ `left` or `right` in that case. Though, as @minitech stated, if you want it to span a dynamic width, it may be easier in JS. Also, you'll want to set `animation-iteration-count: infinite` to do it continously, and `animation-direction: alternate` to get the back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you're using two different properties, `right` and `left`. Although they both position, you must use the same property to perform the transition. If your container is fixed-width, then it's simple; just use `left` instead of `right` or vice-versa for both `from` and `to`.

On the other hand, if the width is dynamic, you're out of luck; use JavaScript instead.